Print more than one digit using jump only NOT allowed to use loops or stack
I am not allowed to use loop for print the sum, I have to use jump only
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
input_buffer1 db 10 DUP ('$')   ; Define a buffer to store the first input string
input_buffer2 db 10 DUP ('$')   ; Define a buffer to store the second input string
message1 db 'Enter the first integer: $' ; Prompt message for the first input
message2 db 'Enter the second integer: $' ; Prompt message for the second input
newline db 13, 10, '$'      ; Newline character to print a newline
result_message db 'The sum is: $'  ; Message for printing the sum

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data            ; Load the address of the data segment into AX
    mov ds, ax               ; Set DS to point to the data segment

    ; Prompt for the first input
    mov ah, 09h              
    mov dx, offset message1
    int 21h

    ; Read the first input
    mov ah, 0Ah              ; Function to read a string
    mov dx, offset input_buffer1
    int 21h                  ; Call interrupt 21h

      ; Print a newline character
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset newline
    int 21h
   
    ; Prompt for the second input
    mov ah, 09h              
    mov dx, offset message2
    int 21h

    ; Read the second input
    mov ah, 0Ah              ; Function to read a string
    mov dx, offset input_buffer2
    int 21h                  ; Call interrupt 21h

    ; Convert the first input to integer
    mov si, offset input_buffer1 + 2   ; Skip the first two bytes (length and '$')
    mov al, [si]                        ; Load the first character
    sub al, '0'                         ; Convert ASCII character to integer
    mov bl, al                          ; Save the integer in BL

    ; Convert the second input to integer
    mov si, offset input_buffer2 + 2   ; Skip the first two bytes (length and '$')
    mov al, [si]                        ; Load the first character
    sub al, '0'                         ; Convert ASCII character to integer
    add bl, al                          ; Add the second input (AL) to the first input (BL)

   
      ; Print a newline character
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset newline
    int 21h
   
    ; Print the sum
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset result_message
    int 21h

    ; Convert the sum to ASCII and print
    mov dl, bl              ; Move the result to DL for printing
    add dl, '0'             ; Convert integer to ASCII character
    mov ah, 02h             ; Function to print a character
    int 21h                 ; Call interrupt 21h

   

    
end main 


That is a silly constraint. Anyway, are your inputs still limited to a single digit? Then just do a conditional check if the result is greater than or equal to 10 and print a leading 1 and subtract 10 to get the second digit.

You're supposed to ask a question.  If you have a question, what is it?  (Questions like solve my problem statement are not really valid here, so you have to ask something technical that will help you make progress.)

The limit of digits is three for the inputs. I am new to StackOverflow. Thanks for your advice, Erik.

; finding multiplication of x and n
mov ax, bx
mul cx
mov di, offset value_mul ; store multiplication result in value_mul
; converting multiplication result to ASCII
mov cx, 10
mov bx, 5 ; buffer size to 5

mult:
    xor dx, dx
    div cx
    add dl, '0'
    mov [di+bx], dl
    dec bx
    cmp ax, 0
    jnz mult
    
; printing multiplication result
mov dx, offset result_mul
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov dx, offset value_mul 
int 21h


when I try to add another operation to the same code, it gives the wrong answer.

So how can I add more than one operation to the same code without overwriting variables?

Your code is giving "wrong" answer because you expected/wanted different one, not because the computer is broken. You can use debugger and find out precisely how the "wrong" answer happens. If the input values were wrong, operation was wrong, output (of otherwise correct value) is wrong, or all of that and fix each issue by adjusting the code. Don't feel helpless when you see wrong result of assembly code, writing these tiny exercises in asm is actually one of the easiest things to debug and fix, as you can find out precisely by single stepping over each instruction, what is the CPU doing.

"without overwriting variables" - in asm you usually work with CPU registers, which are like global variables. When you set some register to new value, the old one is gone. So to preserve for example "input value 1" you have to either "park" it to some spare register which is not modified, and re-fetch it from that each time you need the value, or store it in dedicated memory (often how variables are implemented in higher level language), and re-fetch it from that memory place when you need it.

org 100h
.data
result db 10,13,"Result of addition: $"
value db "00000 $"
newline db 10, 13, '$'
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 0
; finding addition
mov ax, 6
add ax, 3
;converting result to ASCII
mov cx, 10
mov di, offset value
mov bx, 4

convert_to_ascii:
    xor dx, dx
    div cx
    add dl, '0'
    mov [di+bx], dl
    dec bx
    cmp ax, 0
    jnz convert_to_ascii

; printing result
mov dx, offset result
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov dx, offset value 
int 21h  
mov ah, 00h
int 21h
main endp

end mains

jnz convert_to_ascii is a looping branch instruction.
